# Function to automatically write a sentence given a vector and condition in R

Tags: r

Please consider this fruity example:

```
canada <- c(100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 80, 100, 100)
korea <- c(100, 30, 100, 100, 100, 100, 30, 100, 100)
brazil <- c(100, 100, 100, 30, 100, 100, 100, 30, 100)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi", "grape", "monkfruit", "strawberry", "melon", "pineapple")
```

And, the following premises:

1) I do not know the average prices for each column.

2) I am comparing each fruit price against its column averages.

I want to create the following sentence:

```
> price("korea")
> Every fruit costs above average except orange and strawberry.
```

So, this is what I tried so far:

```
price <- function(val){
  # General Functions ----
  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  score.max <- c(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]

  if (score.min < mean(fruit[, name.min])
      ) 
    cat("This is not exactly the right way to pull only the score that are below average because it only prints the minimum score.")
  }
```

Is there a quick command I can use in lieu of which.min?

Comment: What would be your expected output for the given example ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I edited my question. I want to type "price("korea")" or whichever country, and R would return the names of fruits that do not cost above average.

Comment: Is `colnames(fruit)[fruit["korea",] > colMeans(fruit)]` the result you want?

Comment: Hm.. I would have to use "price("country name")" as the print command due to the nature of the entire bulky script I am working with.

Comment: Depending on how you're using this, you may want the addition of grammar for these lists (i.e. commas, etc.). See my answer if that would help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I will certainly face situations where I will take lessons from your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
 price=function(val){
   cat("Every fruit costs above average except",
       names(which(!fruit[val,]>colMeans(fruit))))
  }
```

Well I used a condition of strictly greater. If you want you can use `>=`

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to have R print a sentence that says, "In [country], all fruit costs above average except [fruit names]," then please see the answer below which prints a grammatically accurate sentence depending on the length of the vector (e.g. number of fruits).

```
Canada <- c(100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 80, 100, 100)
Korea <- c(100, 30, 100, 100, 100, 100, 30, 100, 100)
Brazil <- c(100, 100, 100, 30, 100, 100, 100, 30, 100)
fruit <- rbind(Canada, Korea, Brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi", "grape",    
                     "monkfruit", "strawberry", "melon", "pineapple")

price <- function(country,data){
  x <- names(which(!data[country,]>colMeans(data)))
  grammar <- function(x){
    setlength <- length(x)
    if(length(1:setlength)==1){
      setlist <- paste(x)
    } else {
      if(length(1:setlength)==2){
        setlist <- as.character(paste(x[1],"and",x[2]))
      } else {
        setlist <- as.character(paste0(
          paste(x[1:length(x)-1], collapse=", "),
                ", and ", x[length(x)])
        )
      }
    }
  }
  cat(paste0("In ",country,
               ", every fruit costs above average except ",
               grammar(x),"."))

price("Korea",fruit)
```

## Output:

```
"In Korea, every fruit costs above average except apple, orange,   
banana, grape, monkfruit, strawberry, and pineapple."
```